# Item cart price and compare price duplicating

Tags: shopify, liquid

If I have more than one variant the price and compare price duplicate, say I have Black and tall variants, it would be $200 two times next to each.

How can I only show it once?

This is my code:

> {% assign beforePrice = priceCompare | times: item.quantity %}
>
> {{ item.variant.options[forloop.index0] }}   {{ item.product.price[forloop.index0] }}
>
> {% if item.product.compare_at_price > item.product.price %}   {{ beforePrice | money }}    {% endif %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want it to output once on the first iteration of the loop and assuming you're looping over variants (it might help to see all of your loop) you can use [forloop.first](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/for-loops#forloop-first)

```
{% if forloop.first %}
  {{ item.variant.options[forloop.index0] }} {{ item.product.price[forloop.index0] }}
{% endif %}
```

Or you might find that you can just dispense with the loop and do

```
{{ item.variant.options.first }} {{ item.product.price.first }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mike, I was honestly stuck! It's working flawlessly now <3